# How can I switch repositories in git bash so I can add changes to each repository?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am working on two different projects. Each of projects has own repository. How can I switch repositories in git bash so I can add changes to each repository? Let's say Project1 and Project2. These are two different independent projects so changes added to Project1 shouldn't affect Project2.

Comment: @Shawn The question is quite clear, if you think about it. Don't close questions _you_ can't understand, some people will. Reopening.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I switch repositories in git bash so I can add changes to each repository?

You just `cd <project>` to that project's directory and invoke `git` from there. `git` looks for `.git` directory in your current directory and if not found it goes up a directory and repeats.

Alternatively, use `-C` command line option for [`git`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/git.1.html) to avoid having to switch current directories with `cd`, e.g. `git -C ~/src/project_1 ...`.

Comment: It doesn't exactly look _in_ the current directory.

Comment: @matt You are quite right, updated.